# VueJs 2 custom directive to close when clicked outside not working

Tags: vuejs2

I'm working on a vuejs component in which if you click outside of the combobox after you clicked on it, it's supposed to close.

My problem it's that the custom directive it's no working, the program compiles but in the browser i get this error:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in directive click-outside bind hook: "TypeError: Cannot set property 'event' of undefined"
```

This is the code of my component:

```
<template>
  <div class="form-group" v-click-outside="hide">
  <label v-if="label" for="combobox" class="control-label" v-tack>{{ label }}:</label>
    <input id="combobox"
    class="form-control combo-box-control"
    v-on:keyup="filter(searchText,options)"
    v-model="searchText"
    :placeholder="placeholder"
    v-on:click="showAllOptions()" :disabled="isDisabled">
        <template v-if="showAutocomplete">
        <div class="combobox-list">
            <p class="combobox-options" :key="item.id" v-for="item in listFiltered" v-on:click="optionSelected(item)">{{item.text}}</p>
        </div>
        </template>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      listFiltered: [],
      searchText: '',
      showAutocomplete: false
    }
  },
  props: {
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    options: Array,
    label: String,
    isDisabled: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    selectedOption: Object,
    placeholder: String
  },
  methods: {
    filter (word, array) {
      if (word === undefined) {
        this.showAutocomplete = false
        this.listFiltered = []
        return
      }
      this.showAutocomplete = true
      this.listFiltered = array.filter(function (item) {
        return item.text.toLowerCase().includes(word.toLowerCase())
      })
    },
    optionSelected (item) {
      this.searchText = item.text
      this.showAutocomplete = false
      if (item !== undefined) {
        this.$emit('change', { name: this.name, item: item })
      }
    },
    showAllOptions () {
      this.listFiltered = this.options
      this.showAutocomplete = !this.showAutocomplete
    },
    hide () {
      this.showAutocomplete = false
    }
  }
}
</script>
<style>
.form-group{
    position:relative;
}
.form-group input{
    width:100%;
}

input.combo-box-control:active{
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px 1px 0 1px;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
  border-color: #96c8da;
}

.form-control.combo-box-control:focus{
  border-color: #96c8da;
}

.combobox-list{
    position:relative;
    height:154px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:white;
    overflow-y:auto;
    text-align:justify;
    z-index: 5;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #96c8da;
    border-width: 0 1px 1px 1px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
    top: -3px;
}

.combobox-options{
    padding:6px 0;
    margin:0;
}
.combobox-options:hover{
    background-color:#d9d9d9;
}
</style>
```

and the main.js:

```
Vue.directive('click-outside', {
  bind: function (el, binding, vnode) {
    this.event = function (event) {
      if (!(el === event.target || el.contains(event.target))) {
        vnode.context[binding.expression](event)
      }
    }
    document.body.addEventListener('click', this.event)
  },
  unbind: function (el) {
    document.body.removeEventListener('click', this.event)
  }
})
```

the problem is in the line  `this.event = function (event) {` because the error says `Cannot set property 'event' of undefined`, so this is undefined.
Not sure how to define this, inside the directive.

I'm using this example to make it work with my custom component: https://jsfiddle.net/Linusborg/yzm8t8jq/
Did i missed something? 
**Update:** Turns out the code from the example is from a vuejs 1.x, although i found a similar example in vuejs 2.1 https://jsfiddle.net/y0rpfecd/, still get the same error.

Comment: If you're going to be re-using this directive in multiple components (presumably that's why you're making it a directive), you probably want to have a single event handler, not a separate handler for each component. In that case, you can store a reference to the handler as a static variable.

Comment: @StephenThomas Of course, i just wanted to test the directive without the hassle of making another file for it and the importing the directive in the component.

Comment: Well, as you've discovered, directives don't have access to components, only to DOM elements. That's mostly the point of directives as they're intended for ["low-level DOM access on plain elements"](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html#Intro). So indeed there is no defined `this` in the directive hooks. For testing, you can define a static global in your module and use that to store a reference to the handler.

Comment: @StephenThomas How is possible for the examples i posted to be working?

Comment: Because in the Vue2 example `this` is the global `window`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You may have found answer to it. Hope somebody find it useful.

I recently tested click-outside directive in my side project. 
Just replace this.event with window.event in directive code. And it works perfect!!

directive.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';

Vue.directive('click-outside', {
    bind: function (el, binding, vnode) {
        window.event = function (event) {
            if (!(el == event.target || el.contains(event.target))) {
                vnode.context[binding.expression](event);
            }
        };
        document.body.addEventListener('click', window.event)
    },
    unbind: function (el) {
        document.body.removeEventListener('click', window.event)
    },
});
```

To use in component: Just import directive.

```
<template>
  <div class="form-group" v-click-outside="hide">
  <label v-if="label" for="combobox" class="control-label" v-tack>{{ label }}:</label>
    <input id="combobox"
    class="form-control combo-box-control"
    v-on:keyup="filter(searchText,options)"
    v-model="searchText"
    :placeholder="placeholder"
    v-on:click="showAllOptions()" :disabled="isDisabled">
        <template v-if="showAutocomplete">
        <div class="combobox-list">
            <p class="combobox-options" :key="item.id" v-for="item in listFiltered" v-on:click="optionSelected(item)">{{item.text}}</p>
        </div>
        </template>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import clickOutside from '../directive';
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      listFiltered: [],
      searchText: '',
      showAutocomplete: false
    }
  },
  props: {
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    options: Array,
    label: String,
    isDisabled: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    selectedOption: Object,
    placeholder: String
  },
  methods: {
    filter (word, array) {
      if (word === undefined) {
        this.showAutocomplete = false
        this.listFiltered = []
        return
      }
      this.showAutocomplete = true
      this.listFiltered = array.filter(function (item) {
        return item.text.toLowerCase().includes(word.toLowerCase())
      })
    },
    optionSelected (item) {
      this.searchText = item.text
      this.showAutocomplete = false
      if (item !== undefined) {
        this.$emit('change', { name: this.name, item: item })
      }
    },
    showAllOptions () {
      this.listFiltered = this.options
      this.showAutocomplete = !this.showAutocomplete
    },
    hide () {
      this.showAutocomplete = false
    }
  }
}
</script>
<style>
.form-group{
    position:relative;
}
.form-group input{
    width:100%;
}

input.combo-box-control:active{
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px 1px 0 1px;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
  border-color: #96c8da;
}

.form-control.combo-box-control:focus{
  border-color: #96c8da;
}

.combobox-list{
    position:relative;
    height:154px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:white;
    overflow-y:auto;
    text-align:justify;
    z-index: 5;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #96c8da;
    border-width: 0 1px 1px 1px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
    top: -3px;
}

.combobox-options{
    padding:6px 0;
    margin:0;
}
.combobox-options:hover{
    background-color:#d9d9d9;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Great and clean solution!